# Does location.reload() maintain the current scrollbar position?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The title is basically the question.

I'm new to JavaScript and jQuery, and I'm still experimenting with this stuff.

I have a page that makes a post request using jQuery when a button is clicked. That request deletes a record from the database, so I added `location.reload()` when the request is done to see the result. I just noticed that it refreshes the page and also maintains the scroll position. I just want to verify, **does `location.reload()` maintains the current scrollbar position?**

Comment: location.reload() does nothing. Maintaining the scroll position is the browser's work.

Comment: @scrowler I just want to verify. See, Aalain Jacamet Forte say's it's the browser not javascript itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question could be simply answered just scroll down to any website then press f5 to refresh the page and you'll see the scroll position where you were scrolled down. So, `location.reload()` also maintains the current scrollbar position.